# Unicorn is not starting after upgrade from gitlab 6.0 to 6.2

Tags: ruby, unicorn, gitlab

I recently update from gitlab 6.0 to 6.2 and got an issue on starting unicorn after:

```
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:16.934411 #5391]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:39.929592 #5391]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket fd=16
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:39.929976 #5391]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=17
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:39.934823 #5391]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:39.954384 #5400]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2013-11-25T15:18:39.963827 #5403]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
E, [2013-11-26T15:28:03.348742 #5391] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5394 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=unknown
I, [2013-11-26T15:28:03.549345 #5391]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5400 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2013-11-26T15:28:03.749781 #5391]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5403 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2013-11-26T15:28:03.749973 #5391]  INFO -- : master complete
I, [2013-11-26T15:58:50.547084 #6212]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 51 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:103:in `initialize'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `new'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `instance'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:37:in `[]'
        from /home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/git/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:4:in `require'
        from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
        from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong there?
It's running on a Ubuntu 12.04 and I had an isue during the update with receiving of packages repoted at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5694. Not sure whether it's related.

Comment: Paste your YAML file, it probably has bad syntax.

Comment: Unicorn? It's the default from https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-2-stable/config/unicorn.rb.example

Comment: No, gitlab.yml had a config issue (wrong indent). Fixed it and it helped. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was a wrong gitlab.yml file. During merging the changes from 6.2 I put in a wrong indention. Having this fixed, it's running now.